# Applying jQuery selector [attribute*=value] with Traversing on click function

Tags: jquery, accordion, selector

Basically, i would like a specific div section along with its child to show it's content after clicking a button. And to achieve my goal, i believe I would have to use a jQuery selector, and Traversing.

This is the script:

```
$('ul>li').click(function(e) {
    var currentAnchor = $(this);
    $("[title*='" + currentAnchor.text() + "']").show();
    $("[title*='" + currentAnchor.text() + "']").find('.contentbox').show(); <-- i think this is where i'm having issue with
    $(".contentbox:not([title*='" + currentAnchor.text() + "'])").hide();
});
```

HTML

```
    <ul>
    <li>Communications</li>
    <li>Portal</li>
    <li>Website</li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="contentbox" title="Communications" style="display:none;">
        Parent 1 - Communications, with children
        <div class="contentbox" style="display:none; margin-left:5px;">
            Single child with the same pattern as parent
            <div class="contentbox" style="display:none; margin-left:10px;">
              Single sub-child with the same pattern as parent
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="contentbox" title="Portal" style="display:none;">
        Parent 2 - Portal, with children
        <div class="contentbox" style="display:none; margin-left:5px;">
            Single child with the same pattern as parent
            <div class="contentbox" style="display:none; margin-left:10px;">
              Single sub-child with the same pattern as parent
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="contentbox" title="Website" style="display:none;">
        Parent 3 - Website, with children
        <div class="contentbox" style="display:none; margin-left:5px;">
            Single child with the same pattern as parent
            <div class="contentbox" style="display:none; margin-left:10px;">
              Single sub-child with the same pattern as parent
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my workarea in JSFiddle for this test: http://jsfiddle.net/Rgohing/zm9f4Lqv/33/

The onclick function works only on the parent divs, but does not seems to work in its children.

```
$("[title*='" + currentAnchor.text() + "']").show(); <-- works on the parent divs
$("[title*='" + currentAnchor.text() + "']").find('.contentbox').show(); <-- not working
```

Thanks in advance. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The last line does reverse of what second last line does. You show the children then hide them on the next line. And both lines do work. Comment out the last line and you will see the children. Why are all the children hidden anyway? Not really clear how this whole structure is supposed to work

Comment: Also suggest not using the same class on the outer contentbox as you do for it's children. There are also multiple simpler ways to make the relationship between the `<li>` and the content than using title attribute and text from the `<li>`. Using id on the content panels and a data attribute on the <li> for example. Or using `index()`

Comment: It does work if i remove the 2nd line, but the goal is to make sure that all the hidden child div of the parent div with specific title are displayed as well.

Comment: OK but if parent is hidden all it's children will be also

Comment: Thanks!  I just realized that now, and changed the class of children. I probably missed it bcoz im sleepy when i was doing it yesterday.